# updated minecraft on ipads

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Both my children used to play in each other worlds on two separate iPads, since upgrading the minecraft every time they try to play together it keeps just saying invalid name.

Answer (score 0):

On the tablet getting the error, change the name so that there are no spaces or special characters.  This seems to have changed as a requirement with the latest edition.